# What if the UI metadata is stored in Database? What scenarios I need to consider before designing this type of application?

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am working on a .NET application and we are storing our UI elements in database(UI interface metadata). Can someone guide me what scenarios I need to consider in terms of Maintenance, Performance, Deployment, upgrades of application while designing?

What are trade offs in storing UI metadata in XML and UI metadata in database?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help to define some examples of the metadata you are storing.

Some things I think of when you say metadata for the UI:

1. Values of dropdowns. A list of states as an example.
2. Dynamically created UI elements. Can add a textbox to a form via the database.
3. Colors, fonts, alignments, etc.  "A red button aligned to the left"

Each has pros and cons to being in the database.

From experience, when putting too much UI information in the database, the application becomes very hard to reason about. You'll render the UI and it won't look right. Then you spend half the day going through your code and your database trying to figure out why. You'll flip a few bits in the database and render the UI again and wonder why it didn't work.

Also there is a ton of boilerplate code generated when storing too much information about the UI in the database.

Some questions to answer for each UI element:

"Would this be easier to maintain if it was just hard coded in the UI?" It's easier to change HTML in an HTML editor instead of via the database.

"Will this UI element need to change a lot over time?" Unless some user needs to update/change/modify that element, leave it hard coded.

"Do I really want a ton of database tables for UI elements?" It can become a nightmare to maintain. For example, a survey of questions and answers might produce 5-10 tables.

I'd recommend trying to keep the UI elements as much as possible in the application. Only when absolutely necessary should you write them to the database.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. What if I have a toolkit to edit UI elements in database in which user can add, edit, delete different controls. Will there be any customization issues even if I have toolkit?

Comment: I don't think there would be customization issues. If the toolkit works well, it should be fine. I would suggest designing the database so that UI elements could be copied from server to server. That will help for testing and QA. For example, if you have 10 UI elements on production and one has a bug ... you'll want to copy those down to your local environment and have them running without any problems. Very helpful.